# Child ActivityForResult problem in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i one TabGroupActivity as main , inside that tabhost i have Parent and Child Activity, from that Child Activity i launched new Activity not inside tab , launched as separate main Activity,

from child Activity i going to do following thing,

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(SubCategories.this,
            loadingCamera.class),CAM_SUBCAT);
        //SubCategories.this.finish();



 ......
.....





protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
switch(requestCode) {
case CAM_SUBCAT: 
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    System.out.println("sdfg");
     SubCategories.this.finish();

  }

}
```

from the launched  activity setback the result,

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("success","cam_subcat");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

but the child activity is not got any response from the activity launched, i need to handle that activity that activity.

If any knows the solution means help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following link. It has sample code on `startActivityForResult`

http://rahulonblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

In the starter Activity try:

```
startActivityForResult(CAM_SUBCAT);
```

the launcher activity's onActivityResult() method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
switch(requestCode) {
case CAM_SUBCAT: 
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
  {
     Log.e("sdfg");
     SubCategories.this.finish();
  }
}
```

Your code that sets the return value is fine. But remember if you want to retrieve the data stored in the returned `Intent`, use the `data` argument received in `onActivityResult` method instead of that obtained by `getIntent()`.